# How to submit job from compute node to another compute node?

Tags: linux, gridengine

Currently I am working on a SGE cluster, and I could submit jobs using `qsub` in the head node, but what I want to do now is to create new jobs and submit jobs from one compute node to another, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

in the SGE configuration you need to add the nodes you wish to submit from, to the list of submit hosts. You can do this via `qmon` or `qconf` (see: `qconf -as`, `qconf -ds` and `qconf -ss`).

Best you check the manual page of qconf:

```
man qconf
```